# OrderBy does not change list when sorting a list according to date

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a struct and a list as follow, I just wanted to sort the Inputpoints according to date. I have used the following commands but I can not see any sorting.

```
public struct Points
{
    public Date Date;
    public double Quantity;
}
_test = new List<Points>(InputPoints);
_test.OrderBy(t => t.Date);
```

Answer (score 9):

Calling `_test.OrderBy(t => t.Date)` does **not** change the contents of `_test` itself, but rather returns a sorted `IOrderedEnumerable<Points>`. You can turn this back into a `List<Points>` using `ToList()`. So all in all

```
_test = _test.OrderBy(t => t.Date).ToList();
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Specifically it returns an `IOrderedEnumerable<Points>`.

Comment: Absolutely right, adjusted the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From MSDN documentation:

"This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate return value is an object that stores all the information that is required to perform the action. The query represented by this method is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its GetEnumerator method directly or by using foreach in Visual C# or For Each in Visual Basic."

Which means you have to use the value returned by OrderBy() in order to get sorted results.

Answer (score 0):

```
_test =_test.OrderBy(t => t.Date).ToList();
```

Comment: Please a bit of explanation.